# How to avoid `tmux` window closes, when repeatably pressing `Ctrl-C` to terminate a terminal application?

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, tmux

> How to avoid `tmux` window closes, when repeatably pressing `Ctrl-C` to terminate a terminal application?

I often experience that `tmux` closes the window, consisting of a **single pane**, when I terminate a terminal application, like a Python script, by repeatably pressing `Ctrl-C` to terminate all threads.

If these `Ctrl-C` presses occur too fast, then the `tmux` window closes without issuing a prompt. In particular, I need to press `Ctrl-C` very carefully, with time between each key press, to avoid the `tmux` window closes.

Does anyone experience the same problem, and know how to fix it?

**Version**:

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.1
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0)
```

Comment: Can you tell it's the tmux window that closes first because of Ctrl+C? Maybe it's the shell in the only pane of the window? Is there a shell in the first place? What shell? Or do you run other terminal applications in tmux panes/windows directly? What version of tmux?

Comment: Also, what shell are you using?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - see updated question. Yes, there is only a **single pane** in the window. The shell is `bash`. Maybe, you are right, it's the shell that terminates.

Comment: @AndyDalton - I'm using `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on tmux's `remain-on-exit` option and it will not kill panes or windows when the program inside exits but instead wait until you explicitly do it with `C-b x` or similar. In `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g remain-on-exit on
```

Alternatively you could see if your shell has an option to avoid this - for exmaple the `ignoreeof` option in Bourne shells (`set -o ignoreeof` in your shell profile).

Comment: Do you konw if pressing `Ctrl-C` repeatedly would result in EOF being sent?

Comment: Normally it is `C-d` not `C-c` for EOF in the shell, but I don't know what else will cause the shell to exit. Maybe Python is doing something funny.